# Metadata Service not showing up in Term Store Management Tool

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata

The Managed Metadata Service appears to be set up properly and has several Groups and Term Sets defined via Central Admin, but when I navigate to the Term Store Management Tool within a site, I see nothing.  I'm logged in with the same account that I configured the service with in CA; it's set up as a Farm Admin, Site Collection Admin, and Managed Metadata Service Admin.  Any suggestions on what might cause this?

[image]

Comment: Basic question, is the Metadata service running?

Comment: Yes, the status is listed as Started in CA.  I can also see the web service URL in the ULS logs and that is resolving OK, e.g.: http://app2:32843/d7fa8f322d6c4a12bc8ea8adc807ba1c/MetadataWebService.svc

Comment: Is it added to the default proxy group under "Service application associations"? Go to "Application management" under "Service applications", click on "Configure service application associations" and select "service applications" as a view in the top right corner. Make sure that your service shows up with the rest of your services.

Comment: Yes, it's listed there under Service Applications.

Comment: Is MMS services associated with the Central Admin Web app? if not do it....Un associate the MMS from the Web App and re associate it

Comment: Hmm, the CA web app is not listed under Service App Associations, but if I go to Manage Web Apps, select the CA web app, and click Service Connections, the MMS is checked and I'm not able to uncheck any of the listed associations in that dialog.  Actually that is the case for all of the web apps.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a javascript error that was preventing the taxonomy UI from loading completely.